# Pydivert - modify a packet

Tags: python, windows, sockets, tcp, winsock

Pydivert is a python binding for WinDivert that helps mangling packets.

The example from the [docs](https://pypi.org/project/pydivert/) works fine.

```
import pydivert

with pydivert.WinDivert("tcp.DstPort == 1234 or tcp.SrcPort == 80") as w:
    for packet in w:
        if packet.dst_port == 1234:
            print(">") # packet to the server
            packet.dst_port = 80
        if packet.src_port == 80:
            print("<") # reply from the server
            packet.src_port = 1234
        w.send(packet)
```

However, Trying to modify a packet - (by accessing it's value and replace it with something else) I see that the end packet is left un-modified.

Seems like other people experienced the same, heres a comment found in [another github project](https://github.com/fireeye/flare-fakenet-ng/blob/master/fakenet/diverters/windows.py) implementing this:

(at line 30 and forward):

```
# Packet mangling properties are extended here to also write the data to
# the pydivert.Packet object. This is because there appears to be no way to
# populate the pydivert.Packet object with plain octets unless you can also
# provide @interface and @direction arguments which do not appear at a
# glance to be directly available as attributes of pydivert.Packet,
# according to https://ffalcinelli.github.io/pydivert/
#
# Perhaps we can get these from wd_addr?
```

I don't understand what they are saying in the github project, but seems to be that we need to create a packet class and fill in some properties (help).

Q1 - How would I go about populating a packet with pydivert?

Q2 - What do I need to do to be able to modify a packet with pydivert?